# Vertical scroll not working when I call bootstrap modal from another modal?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-modal

I have a modal and call other modal from it and when I click on submit or cancel 2nd modal, vertical scrollbar not working and page fixed and remain unmoved.

```html
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">

        <h4 class="modal-title">Product</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-                        dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you post your all code here http://www.bootply.com/new#

Comment: @IsmailFarooq ,Ican't,I don't have permission for copy in office.But,as I said befor are 2 simple modals.

Comment: actually the above code is not enough to understand whats wrong with that

Comment: This type of problem has been addressed many times here on SO, search for the solution, reason of the problem is that "Bootstrap doesn't support stacked/simultaneous/overlapping modals" http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals